# Can i use a built in fingerprint reader to test my application?

Tags: vb.net, fingerprint

I want to build an attendance application in vb.net using visual studio, can I use the fingerprint reader of my laptop to test the application?

Comment: Hard to know, depends on what interfaces/api is exposed by your figure print scanner and as you have given exactly zilch information nobody is going to be able to give you any sort of reliable answer

Comment: Yes you can. You now need to go and research the topic, make an attempt to use the information you find and then come back if and when you encounter an actual issue. SO is intended for specific problems but your question is way too general. Not knowing how to do something is not a problem. It's a reason to research how to do that thing. When you think you know how but what you doesn't work, that is a problem.

Comment: I last had to mess with fingerprint readers back in 2007. At that time, every model was different, each with it's own API and SDK. It's possible things have improved since then.